# React Native: drawer doesn't close when screen background is tapped on

Tags: react-native

I have a React application in which I have implemented `createDrawernavigator` with `createStackNavigator`. When I touch the button, the drawer opens. That works fine, but the drawer is not closing after the drawer is opened and when I tap on the screen background or swipe from right to left.

Code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigator, Navigation, DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";
import Login from "./screens/LoginScreen/Login";
import DefaultPreference from 'react-native-default-preference';
import Icon from "./components/Icons";
import { View, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Platform, TouchableOpacity, Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import DrawerScreen from './screens/DrawerScreen'
import color from "./styles/color"
import Machines from "./screens/MachineListScreen/Machines";
import MachineInfo from './screens/MachineInfo/MachineInfo'
import Machine from './screens/MachineInfo/Machine'
// import Devices from "./screens/DeviceListScreen/Devices";
// import WifiConfigs from "./screens/WiFiConfigScreen/WiFiConfig";
import AuthLoading from './screens/AuthLoading'
import ChangePassword from './screens/ChangePasswordScreen/ChangePassword'
import ForgotPassword from './screens/ChangePasswordScreen/ForgotPassword'
import Analyze from './screens/Analyze/AnalyzeScreen'
import Report from './screens/Reports/Report'
import Search from 'react-native-search-box'
import About from './screens/About/About'
// import Search from 'react-native-search-box';
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width
var customerName = ''
DefaultPreference.get('customerName').then((val) => {
  customerName = val
})
const MachineStack = createStackNavigator({
  Machines: {
    screen: Machines,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      headerTitle: () => {
        return <View style={{ width: width * 0.8, alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 2 }}>
          <Search
            backgroundColor={color.primary}
            deleteButtonStyle={{ fontSize: 20 }}
            placeholder={'Search in ' + customerName}
            onDelete={() => navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].params.handleCancel()}
            onCancel={() => navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].params.handleCancel()}
            onChangeText={(text) => navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index].params.handleChange(text)}
          />
        </View>
      },
      headerLeft:
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()) }}>
        <MenuImage navigation={navigation} />
      </TouchableOpacity>,
    }),

  },
  Machine: { screen: Machine },
  MachineInfo: { screen: MachineInfo },
  Analyze: { screen: Analyze },
  Report: { screen: Report },
  PasswordScreen: { screen: ChangePassword },
  AboutScreen: { screen: About }
},
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      // Title to appear in status bar
      headerStyle: {
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#2196F3"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    })
  })

// Creates drawernavigator.
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  MachineStack: {
    screen: MachineStack
  }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'MachineStack',
    contentComponent: DrawerScreen,
  }
);

const MenuImage = ({ navigation }) => {
  if (!navigation.state.isDrawerOpen) {
    return <Icon style={styles.drawerIcn} name='menu' size={24} />
  } else {
    return <Icon style={styles.drawerIcn} name='arrow-back' size={24} />
  }
}

// stacknavigator
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Login: Login, ChangePassword: ChangePassword, ForgotPassword: ForgotPassword });

// switchnavigator.
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
    App: Drawer,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawerIcn: {
    color: '#fff',
    padding: 10
  }
})
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Only background screen

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the left component code part to this:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    . . .
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()) }}>
        <MenuImage navigation={navigation} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }
},
```

Also, I believe that you are missing the `return {` on the beginning of the `navigationOptions`

Hope it helps.

More information here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html

Comment: I tried with above code but it didn't worked for me.When I added return at the begining of navigationoption then menuimage and search bar is invisible.